# How to make a picture in the home section responsive in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image, responsive

I m making a new site with bootstrap and the problem that I have is that my image in the home section (the one that takes the full-screen size is not responsive) if you have a look at [fascia release therapist](http://www.fasciareleasetherapist.com/promovibracussortherapy.html) that the landing page is not really responsive! now if you look at the site home section the image is responsive but I noticed that it is only to a certain point since the background is uniform and my landing page has a lot of stuff in the background and it gets chop away.

here is my HTML code for the landing page home section

```
    <div id="percussion-cover" class="bg-parallax animated fadeIn">

        <div id="percussion-content-box">

            <div id="percussion-content-box-inner" class="text-center">

                <div id="percussion-heading" class="animated zoomIn">
                    <h1>Vibracussor<sup>&reg;</sup> Therapy<br>Eliminate the need for pain medication!</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="percussion-btn" class="animated zoomIn">
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-general btn-white" href="percussiontherapy.html" role="button" title="pain relieve without medication!"> Click here to know more!</a>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>



</section>
```

now CSS

## percussion-cover {

```
height: 100%;


background-image: url("../img/vibracussortherapylandingpage.jpg");
background-image: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```

}

any ideas how I can fix that so it looks nice also on mobile?

thanks for your help

Comment: What you describe as a "background image" is NOT a background image at all. A background image contains, as the name implies, only the **background** and none of the content! What you are doing there is a total violation of the basics 101. All of the text content, as well as all of the smaller images, **cannot** i.e. must not be part of the background image.

Comment: Only that network image i.e. the unimportant stuff should be your background image. Everything else should be laid out using the Bootstrap grid and layout tools. Then everything is gonna be responsive.

Comment: When using a proper background image, Bootstrap will automatically crop the image as needed to fill out what needs to be filled out. That's why you cannot have any of the important content embedded within your background image.

Comment: Thanks, WebDevBooster! I will only keep my web background and for the other stuff i will try to put few things near the middle near the text so it does not get chunk right away!